# Calling a templated member of a class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I've written a class that has a templated member function, mostly because it takes a `std::vector` as an argument, however I'm struggling to find a proper way to call it.

```
class foo(){
    // ...
    template <typename _t> int bar(const std::vector<_t> *values);
    // ...
}
```

when calling this function later with:

```
// ...
foo c;
std::vector<int> v(5,100);
c.bar(&v);
// ...
```

I get the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::bar(std::vector<int>*)’
c.bar(&v);
```

Shouldn't `foo::bar(std::vector<int>*)` conform to the template parameters? Why won't it compile?

Comment: After making the irrelevant parts of your code legal, [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c60537785a9849ee).

Comment: Have you implemented the method body anywhere in your header file?

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg, That would still compile, just not link (like in my reproduction attempt).

Comment: **− 1** not the real code

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
#include <vector>

class foo{
public:
         template <typename _t> int bar(const std::vector<_t> *values) {
            return 1;
         }

};


int main() {
   foo c;
   std::vector<int> v(5,100);
   c.bar(&v);
}
```

If you really need it to not to be inline you can:

```
//from here
#include <vector>

class foo{
public:
         template <typename _t> int bar(const std::vector<_t> *values);

};

template <typename _t> int foo::bar(const std::vector<_t> *values) {
    return 0;
}
//to here - should be in header file to allow compiler to link it!

int main() {
   foo c;
   std::vector<int> v(5,100);
   c.bar(&v);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting ` undefined reference to `int foo::bar<int>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const*)'` when compiling this.

Comment: @joaocandre what compiler do you use?

Comment: It compiles under g++, clang also does not complain: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e70801ee26538dfc I also check visual studio online compiler and it only says an error that foo::bar should return a value... (editing code)

Comment: I'm using g++ on a linux machine, and I actually have a separate .hpp and .cpp for my `foo` class. I realize the above error might be caused by this (I can compile if all the code is on a single .cpp). I'm calling `g++ main.cpp foo.cpp -o main -I /usr/include`.